# Debug.log not showing in console

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textfield, hierarchy

I'm doing a Login System and it's supposed to appear a message in the console through the debug.log when the user input the username or password.

I'm doing the script for the username and password in different script files.

Username script here :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Username : MonoBehaviour {

    public string username;

    public void WritingUsername()
    {
    // store the input from the user in the username string

        username = transform.Find ("UsernameInputField/Text").GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        Debug.Log (username);


    }
}
```

Password script here :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Password : MonoBehaviour {

    public string password;

    public void WritingPassword()
    {
        // store the input from the user in the username string

        password = transform.Find ("PasswordInputField/Text").GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        Debug.Log (password);


    }

}
```

Hierarchy here :

[image]

Is anything wrong ?

Comment: Whats calling `writing`?

Comment: I've made a copy past , now u say i didn't changed the writing function in the password too , but my idea was to make password and username code separately and then when pressing the login button it calls the 2 scripts , those 2 functions and validate them , understand ?

Answer (score 3):

If this really a **debug not showing issue** then please ensure that in **Console Tab** you have selected **Log** option as picture suggested. I have already become crazy using this option :) 
[image]

Comment: then, u have to call WritingUsername() and WritingPassword() on button click

Comment: After 3 years your answer saved my day. most other answers on the internet did not even consider of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the input controls are not the child of the object which holds your script.

[Tranform.Find finds only children](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html)

You can give GameObject.Find a try

Comment: I'm putting the script in the UsernameInputField and in the PasswordInputField , I'm doing it right ? or should i put it in the Text ?

Comment: Try changing PasswordInputField/Text to just "TexT"

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are executing the methods `WritingUsername` and `WritingPassword` from your script, your code should work.

Are you sure you are not getting an empty string, the default value of String?

using `string.Format` usually makes it easier to catch empty logs. It's also prettier.

```
Debug.Log (string.Format("Password: {0}", password));
```

Comment: Using it doesnt show me anything in the console :\ , i can see when i press the child text that when inputing anything  the text (script) changes to what i write in the password field , yet the console keeps showing nothing

Comment: Are you sure you are executing the methods and that the scripts are added to the gameobjects? Do you get any other log messages in the console? Try adding a log in any other place or in void Start.

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding what you mean by  
"Are you sure you are executing the methods" ? I think I'm doing all right , the 2 scripts , username and password are attached to the UsernameInputField and PasswordInputField Parents in the hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure those scripts are attached to something on hierarchy?

Just for testing i would do this on both scripts:

```
void Start (){
    Debug.Log ("Test");
}
```

If you don't see anything try using

```
print ("test");
```

If you still don't see anything, these scripts are not working for some reason or they are not attached to any game object.

IF you are seeing those messages your problem might be on the variable. For example, what you can do is storing (JUST FOR TEST, DON'T DO THAT FOR PUBLISHING) as a global, or using a function with params.

Comment: Yep i can see the messages now , i will check the variables now

Comment: I think it might be something on ".Find" that's why i said you could use function with parameters. You just call the function where you need and give the parameters needed to Print or Debug.

Comment: I haven't yet study much about funtions with parameters , public void WritingPassword(string password) , you mean this for example ?

Comment: yes, and to call that you just simple type WritingPassword(password) on other script.

Comment: Exactly the same ... i really can't figure out what's wrong